# API call returns on postman, but returns a 500 internal server error when called and logged in browser

Tags: php, laravel-5, passport.js

This is related to Laravel 5.4 and its Passport Password Grant.

I have routes for obtaining an access_token for the user to use that works completely fine.

I also have a route to refresh the token should the current access token expire.

When I use Postman to hit the route

```
http://192.168.10.10/refresh
```

I get this back which is valid:

```
"data": {
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi...deleting most of it.",
    "expires_in": 600
}
```

However when I hit the route from the browser, using axios via this code:

```
let  headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
return axios.post("http://192.168.10.10/refresh", {headers: headers}).then(res => {
    if (res) return res;
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err) return err.response;
        });
```

I get an HTTP 500 Error status code.

I'm tailing the laravel log for errors as well and this is the stack trace.

[2017-08-30 07:21:41] local.ERROR: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://192.168.10.10/oauth/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"invalid_request","message":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value,  (truncated...)
 in /home/vagrant/Code/work/vendorgraphs-api/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113

The other part of this error is that it may be a malformed value.

Doesn't make sense to me and I've tried everything from making curl requests directly from PHP code and also used http_query_builder functionality.

```
Cache-Control →no-cache, private
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Type →application/json
```

This is what's set on Postman with the request. I am sending those headers from the browser as well. Any ideas on what might be causing the issue? This is driving me crazy.

```
    public function refreshToken(Request $request) 
{     
    if (!is_null($request)) {
        $refreshToken = $request->cookie(self::REFRESH_TOKEN);

        $http = new Guzzle();
        $response = $http->request('POST','http://192.168.10.10/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
                'refresh_token' => $refreshToken,
                'client_id' => env("PASSWORD_GRANT_CLIENT_ID"),
                'client_secret' => env("PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET"),
                'scope' => '',
            ]
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $this->cookie->queue(
            self::REFRESH_TOKEN,
            $data->refresh_token,
            864000, // 10 days
            null,
            null,
            false,
            true // HttpOnly
        );

        return response()->json([
            'payload' => [
                'access_token' => $data->access_token,
                'expires_in' => $data->expires_in
            ]
        ]);

    } else {
        return response()->json("Could not refresh token", 401);
    }
}
```

[image: The network's tab for the request]

And here's the content for the postman request.

[image]

HERE'S WHERE I'M CONFUSED.

No parameters are being passed through this POST request.
CORS is enabled on my api, not receiving pre-flight errors.
Headers are the same on both requests.
The only difference is, Postman being used and Axios being used.
Nothing changes, except for where the request is being made, via Postman or browser.

Comment: use the network tab in chrome dev tools to inspect the headers of your request from the js, and compare those with your postman request :)

Comment: How are you obtaining you `_token` , what does refresh returns?It would be useful if you could paste some info

Comment: What does the log of your working Postman request look like?

Comment: about the error code. you have in on place the 500 error code and on the other side you 400 error code. Are you sure you are looking at the right log message? I think they should match on both client and server side. Unless there is something that I do not know.

Comment: the 400 error comes from an internal http call to another url, which causes a 500 internal error to be thrown.

Comment: I've updated the PHP code that returns the token.

Comment: @DanielPark, did you ever resolve this? I am having exactly the same issue.

Comment: @forgetso unfortunately no i didn't. I had to just do a work around using different HTTP methods, which made my API not as RESTful as I wanted it to be. but amazon developer support wasn't much help either.

Answer (score 3):

content-type in your browser is text/html
whereas in the postman is application/json

Set the content-type to application/json and it should work

Comment: The OP's axios code in the browser is setting content type to application/json...(see third code block). Be sure you're looking at request headers and not response headers content type.

Comment: You are an unsung hero.